# Using an Android phone as a cordless headset

Tags: wi-fi

I know there are some cordless phones which allow adding Android phones as additional headsets (e.g. http://shop.panasonic.com/shop/model/KX-PRW130W or http://shop.panasonic.com/shop/model/KX-PRX120W). These devices include both a headset and a base receiver. I already have an Android phones, so I only need to a device to transmit calls to my cell phone via WiFi (the base). Is there such device available?

Comment: I know of several apps connecting to the router (which often is a combo of WiFi and telephony router), basically registering as a "landline cordless phone" using VoIP. Is it that what you're asking for? If so, there must be support from both ends (i.e. your "phone box" must support it, and have a matching app – or your "phone box" offers a standard SIP protocol where you can use any SIP app with).

Comment: @Izzy No, The question is not related to VoIP in any way. Please the linked page.

Answer (score 0):

In the links you provided in your question, are the devices that are required.  They have that feature built into the hardware.